# Some method errors in my quadratic program

Tags: java

I am relatively new to the land of Java and google has had no help, this may be a common rookie mistake but I am not exactly sure how to go about debugging. My program is relatively small (1 class) and I figured it couldn't hurt to see if someone could figure out my idiocy. And btw this programs solves quadratics, just for reference <3

My errors (all errors originate from their respective if statements):

> error: method `quadneggative` in class `QuadraticFormula` cannot be
>   applied to given types;
>
> error: method `quadpositive` in class `QuadraticFormula` cannot be applied to given types;
>
> error: method `diszero` in class `QuadraticFormula` cannot be applied to given types;

My program:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class QuadraticFormula {


    public QuadraticFormula() {
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       runnermethod();
    }
    public static double scannermethod()
    {
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input a value:");
        double val = keyboardInput.nextDouble();
        return val;         
    }

    public static double dis(double aval, double bval, double cval)
    {
        double a = aval;
        double b = bval;
        double c = cval;
        double dis = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);

        return dis;     
    }

    public static void diszero(double aval, double bval)
    {
        double a = aval;
        double b = bval;

        double quadzero = (-1*b)/(2*a);

        System.out.print("Your real solution is: x ="+quadzero);
    }

    public static void quadpositive(double aval, double bval, double dis)
    {
        double d = dis;
        double a = aval;
        double b = bval;
        double quadsqr = Math.sqrt(d);
        double quadpostop = (-1*b)+quadsqr;
        double quadnegtop = (-1*b)-quadsqr;

        double quadposall = quadpostop/(2*a);
        double quadnegall = quadnegtop/(2*a);
        System.out.print("Your real solutions are: x ="+quadposall+","+quadnegall+"i");
    }

    public static void quadneggative(double aval, double bval, double dis)
    {
        double d = dis;
        double a = aval;
        double b = bval;
        double quadsqr = Math.sqrt(d*(-1));
        double quadpostop = (-1*b)+quadsqr;
        double quadnegtop = (-1*b)-quadsqr;

        double quadposall = quadpostop/(2*a);
        double quadnegall = quadnegtop/(2*a); 
        System.out.print("Your imaginary solutions are: x ="+quadposall+"i,"+quadnegall+"i");
    }

    public static void runnermethod()
    {
        scannermethod();
        double a = scannermethod();
        double b = scannermethod();
        double c = scannermethod();

        dis(a, b, c);

        double disc = dis(a, b, c);

        if(disc < 0)
        {
            quadneggative();
        }

        if(disc > 0)
        {
            quadpositive();
        }

        if(disc == 0)
        {
            diszero();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: your methods have been clared to have parameters but you don't pass any in. call them like this: `quadpositive(a, b, c);`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. You now provided almost 100 lines of code. That contains three really similar errors.

Comment: *I am not exactly sure how to go about debugging.*  System.out.println is your friend.  Put one after every other line of code if that's what it takes to see the problems.  In this particular case, you need to learn and understand compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the parameters to the methods
it should be like:

```
if(disc < 0) {
    quadneggative(a,b,disc);
}

if(disc > 0) {
    quadpositive(a,b,disc);
}

if(disc == 0) {
    diszero(a,b);
}
```